# Rails 4.2.0- Validates Association Counts for has_many Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I search high and low and can't seem to come to find a proper solution for this simple problem.

Essentially, I would like to validates the amount of association between two models.

I read somewhere, and tried using something like,
`validates :attachments, inclusion: { in: 20}`
and failed.

Out of frustration, I removed the code, and don't have anything to show for right now. But I'll add it back when I came across the same problem again.

Thank you for lending your helping hand! = )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a custom validation method to check how many attachments this model has:

```
validate valid_attacments_count?

def valid_attachments_count?
  attachments.count <= 20
end
```

Comment: Down voting because this is not a complete answer